# multiple table sort using same function angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a mediocre in Angularjs and need help on the same.
I have two tables with the same headers and data in the table may or may not be different. I need to sort the data based on the click on header.
I am using same sort function for both tables. 
The problem is when I click  on one header the data on both the tables are getting sorted. I need only that table to be sorted whose header I click. Please help.

Heres the code.

```
<body ng-app="orderByExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <pre>Sorting predicate = {{predicate}}; reverse = {{reverse}}</pre>
    <hr/>
    <button ng-click="predicate=''">Set to unsorted</button>
    <table class="friend">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="order('name')">Name</button>
          <span ng-show="predicate === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="order('phone')">Phone Number</button>
          <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'phone'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="order('age')">Age</button>
          <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'age'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
        <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>


      <table class="friend">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="order('name')">Name</button>
          <span ng-show="predicate === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="order('phone')">Phone Number</button>
          <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'phone'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="order('age')">Age</button>
          <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'age'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
        <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>


(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('orderByExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.friends =
        [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
         {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:35},
         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29}];
    $scope.predicate = 'age';
    $scope.reverse = true;
    $scope.order = function(predicate) {
      $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
      $scope.predicate = predicate;
    };
  }])
.factory("")
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 2):

Both tables are sorting on the same variables, so their display will naturally be identical.

I would make the order and predicate children of a table identifier - we'll use t1 and t2 here, but please use something more identifiable in your own code.

```
$scope.t1 = { predicate: 'age', reverse: true};
$scope.t2 = { predicate: 'age', reverse: true};
```

Now the order function needs to take that identifier:

```
$scope.order = function(predicate, tableId) {
  $scope[tableId].reverse = ($scope[tableId].predicate === predicate) ? !$scope[tableId].reverse : false;
  $scope[tableId].predicate = predicate;
};
```

And finally the order functions and repeaters need to use their table ids:

```
<table class="friend">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <button ng-click="order('name','t1')">Name</button>
      <span ng-show="t1.predicate === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse:t1.reverse}"></span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <button ng-click="order('phone','t1')">Phone Number</button>
      <span class="sortorder" ng-show="t1.predicate === 'phone'" ng-class="{reverse:t1.reverse}"></span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <button ng-click="order('age','t1')">Age</button>
      <span class="sortorder" ng-show="t1.predicate === 'age'" ng-class="{reverse:t1.reverse}"></span>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:t1.predicate:t1.reverse">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Same idea for table 2

If you needed to scale larger, you would probably want to use some kind of a repeater instead of what I just did. I'll leave that exercise to you.

Comment: Solution with directive that would isolate scope would be much sexy tho.

Comment: A full solution would have the friends collection coming from a service or factory so that isolated scope in the presentation would actually work correctly. We're not trying to confuse new Angular developers :)

Comment: Thanks Lathejockey81 :)